# Error building Ionic app using WP8 platform on MAC OSX

Tags: windows-phone-8, ionic-framework

Happy that the Android .apk file I built using "ionic build android" worked on a Samsung Note phone.

I would like to try the same app but on a different hardware which is my Nokia Lumia Windows Phone 8.

So I added the platform wp8 first and it went well.

```
$ ionic platform add wp8
Updated the hooks directory to have execute permissions
WARNING: Applications for platform wp8 can not be built on this OS - darwin.
Adding wp8 project...
Running command: /Users/user01/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-wp8/3.8.2/package/bin/create /Users/user01/repos/myTabs/platforms/wp8 com.ionicframework.mytabs754813 myTabs
Creating Cordova Windows Project:
  App Name  : myTabs
  Namespace : com.ionicframework.mytabs754813
  Path      : /Users/user01/repos/myTabs/platforms/wp8
Copying necessary files to /Users/user01/repos/myTabs/platforms/wp8
Updating project files
Running command: /Users/user01/repos/myTabs/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /Users/user01/repos/myTabs
add to body class: platform-wp8
Installing "cordova-plugin-console" for wp8
Installing "cordova-plugin-device" for wp8
Installing "cordova-plugin-splashscreen" for wp8
Installing "cordova-plugin-statusbar" for wp8
Installing "cordova-plugin-whitelist" for wp8

This plugin is only applicable for versions of cordova-android greater than 4.0. If you have a previous platform version, you do *not* need this plugin since the whitelist will be built in.

Installing "ionic-plugin-keyboard" for wp8
Saving platform to package.json file
A platform already exists - now updating the entry: android platform=android, version=undefined, locator=wp8
```

However, I got an error when I ran "ionic build wp8".

```
$ ionic build wp8
Running command: /Users/user01/repos/myTabs/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /Users/user01/repos/myTabs
add to body class: platform-wp8
Running command: /Users/user01/repos/myTabs/platforms/wp8/cordova/build
ERROR: MSBuild tools not found
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /Users/user01/repos/myTabs/platforms/wp8/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: /Users/user01/repos/myTabs/platforms/wp8/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a closer look at the logs:

> WARNING: Applications for platform wp8 can not be built on this OS - darwin.

It is only possible to build wp8 apps on Windows. Of course, you could use Bootcamp, Parallels or any other virtual machine.

Comment: I didn't see that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can I copy the whole directory of my project then put it on a Windows machine? The build should work right?

Comment: and I only have Windows XP, will I still be able to build it?

Comment: You need Windows 7 or 8 to build WP8 apps, not sure about Ionic. The easiest way on Mac is to get the latest version of Windows and use Bootcamp.

Comment: Cool. It's my first time hearing about Bootcamp. Looks like it's a vm like virtualbox. I'll search for it now. Thanks!